# error in git commit "Errors found not fixable automatically"

Tags: git

how can i fix this error? this recently happened and now i can't commit.

```
$ git commit -m "tests"
No syntax errors detected in D:/file.name
Running Code Sniffer...
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 32: ./vendor/bin/phpcs: Is a directory
Coding standards errors have been detected. Running phpcbf...
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 36: ./vendor/bin/phpcbf: Is a directory
Running Code Sniffer again...
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 39: ./vendor/bin/phpcs: Is a directory
Errors found not fixable automatically
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can force the commit with `git commit -n -m "..."`: the --no-verify option will bypass the pre-commit hook.

But second, you should check why your pre-commit script trigger an error.
And double-check if folders like vendor or bin are supposed to be tracked in stead of being ignored by a `.gitignore` selection rule.

> I don't know why the `vendor` folder is being tracked since it's already added in `.gitignore`

First, you can check if it is ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- vendor
```

Second, if it is tracked, you can delete it while keeping it locally:

```
git rm --cached -r -- vendor
git commit -m "Delete vendor"
```

Then your `.gitignore` rule would apply immediately.

Comment: thank you so much, the -n solved it. but i don't know why the vendor folder is being tracked since it's already added in .gitignore

Comment: @HeeroYuy I have edited the answer regarding the `.gitignore` issue.

Comment: i checked for vendor and this is the result `.gitignore:2:/vendor    vendor`

Comment: Then it needs to be removed (git rm -r --cached), before that rule can apply.